# Ruby on Rails nested resource routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user, comment, and route model as shown:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :routes, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I have the routes.rb file nesting comments and routes within user as shown:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
 resources :comments
 resources :routes
end
```

When I run 'rake routes', the route to the Routes_controller index appears as so:

```
user_routes GET /users/:user_id/routes(.:format) {:action =>"index", :controller=>"routes"}
```

Yet for some reason when a user is signing in, I get a routing error saying that the routes controller cannot be found.  This happens when the system is posting a new session in the session controller.  I know that it attempts to sign in the user, but fails on the redirect.  Any suggestions?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
...
def create
 user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                         params[:session][:password])
 if user.nil?
  flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
  @title = "Sign in"
  render 'new'
 else
  sign_in user
  redirect_to user_routes_path
 end
 end
...
end
```

For some reason, the stack trace wasn't displayed when I redirect to user_routes_path, so I have it direct to root_path and the same thing happens.  Here is the trace for that:

```
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:3:in
  `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___917786942_46449696_315190'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in
  `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__423035099_46500948_0'
```

Comment: Your `user_routes_path` should have at least a `user_id`. But this is not your problem ... Could you add the stack trace of your routing error?

Comment: @mliebelt I added the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give it a try, after reading [Fernandez: The rails 3 way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661) about `redirect_to`.

When you look at the output from `rake routes`, you have the output:

```
user_routes GET /users/:user_id/routes(.:format) {:action =>"index", :controller=>"routes"}
```

The methods you may use to that route are:

- `user_routes_url`: Full URL (with protocol and everything)
- `user_routes_path`: Relative URL to the host

But your `user_routes` tells you another thing: the URL has to contain a `user_id`, and this `user_id` has to come from somewhere. So to call the different url and path methods, you have to look at the arguments:

- `users_path`: no argument, shows all users
- `user_path(@user)`: one argument, because the information about the user is needed. Could be the user, or the `user_id`
- `user_routes_path(@user): needs the user, so that all routes (index view) for one user could be shown.

So include in you source code in the controller:

```
...
else
  sign_in user
  redirect_to user_routes_path(user)
end
...
```

I don't understand the error message you have appended, but I think you should first correct the path call.

Comment: I was at the bookstore today and one of them said the same thing.  Thanks for you help.